# How to handle a datepicker in selenium (python)?

Tags: python, selenium, datepicker

Im currently on a project which fill the information automaticlly. There is a datepicker on the website which I cant click. How to trigger the datepicker to popup etc.

The website is payoneer.com / Login form

```
birthbutton = driver.find_elements_by_name("ctl00$cphBodyContent$PersonalDetails1$datepicker5")
birthbutton.click()
```

Just getting this everytime

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used `find_elements_by_name()` this will return list. You should use

```
find_element_by_name()
```

Now try this.

```
birthbutton = driver.find_element_by_name("ctl00$cphBodyContent$PersonalDetails1$datepicker5")
birthbutton.click()
```

I will suggests use `webdriverwait`.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.payoneer.com")
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='menu-user-menu-container']//ul//li/a[text()='Register']"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME,"ctl00$cphBodyContent$PersonalDetails1$datepicker5"))).click()
```

**Browser Snapshot:**

[image]

Comment: Thats the same thing I posted.

Comment: See my answer `find_element_by_name` not find_elements_by_name

Comment: @VRX : You have posted  `find_elements_by_name()` not `find_element_by_name()` which I have suggested.